# Why did Gabriel interfere with Joseph’s cloak?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, midrash, malach-angel, yosef, parashat-vayeishev

In Ginzberg’s *Legends of the Jews*, a legend is quoted which says that Joseph was eventually found not-guilty of assaulting Mrs Potiphar because, when the Egyptians examined the tear pattern on the cloak he was wearing at the time (tear on the front = guilty, tear on the back = innocent), the Angel Gabriel altered it to make Joseph seem innocent. Quoted below.

Question though… *why* did Gabriel need to interfere? Surely Joseph *was* innocent, so how come the tear needed to be switched round?

Ginzberg says:

> The Egyptians had hesitated to make [Joseph] their viceroy, because
> they shrank from choosing a man accused of adultery for so high an
> office. It was the priests that made the suggestion to examine
> Joseph’s torn garment, which his mistress had submitted as evidence of
> his guilt, and see whether the rent was in front or in back. If it was
> in back, it would show his innocence—he had turned to flee, and his
> temptress had clutched him so that the garment tore. But if the tear
> was in front, then it would be a proof of his guilt—he had used
> violence with the woman, and she had torn the mantle in her efforts to
> defend her honor. The angel Gabriel came and transferred the rent from
> the fore part to the back, and the Egyptians were convinced of
> Joseph’s innocence, and their scruples about raising him to the
> kingship were removed.

Ginzberg’s source is Hadar Z’keinim to Gen 47:22, which reads:

> בשביל שסייעו ליוסף בדינו כי כשרצו להמליך יוסף אמרו המצרים איך נמליך
> איש ששכב עם אשת אדוניו. א"ל הכומרים ראו איפה בגדו נקרע. אם נקרע
> מאחוריו בידוע שלא רצה לבא עליה אלא כשברח קרעתו אשת אדוניו כדי לעכבו
> ואם נקרע לפניו דעו שרצה לבא עליה והיא לא רצתה. בדקו ומצאו הקריעה
> מלאחריו כי גברי"אל הפכה והמליכוהו.

Comment: Interesting. There are other sources that point to there being other "evidence" - see the Targum Yonasan there about her using egg white which was later diproved.

Comment: Also interesting to note the Midrash Lekach Tov - https://www.sefaria.org/Midrash_Lekach_Tov%2C_Genesis.39.12.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en which mentions straight up that his overall opened at the front and when she grabbed him from the back he undid it from the front and fled?